# Scala: pattern matching over a reflect.runtime.universe.Type?

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

how can I do a pattern match over a reflect.runtime.universe.Type?

```
def test(t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type) {
  t match {
    case Int => \\ ...
    case Double => \\ ...
    case String => \\ ... 
    case _ =>  \\ ...
  }
}
```

This dosn't work, as the interpreter complains:

```
error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Int.type
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.Type
Note: if you intended to match against the class, try `case _: Int`
         case Int => // ...
              ^
```

Trying the suggestion does not work either:

```
def test(t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type) {
  t match {
    case _: Int => \\ ...
    case _: Double => \\ ...
    case _: String => \\ ... 
    case _ =>  \\ ...
  }
}    

...

error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Int
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeApi
            case _: Int => // ...
                 ^
```

So what is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: ps.: Using a if-statement, I can do the following: 

    if (t==reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[String]) // ... 

This does, however, not work in the pattern matching syntax:

    t match {
      case reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[String] => \\ ...
      case _ => 
    }

I get the hint error: type typeOf is not a member of scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse
             case reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[String] => fieldMap(pName).set(pVal)

Comment: And another problem: doing the if-statement I find the scala.Int is obviously not the same as Int. However, the result of reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[scala.Int]) is Int, and the result of (t==reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Int]) is false as well as the result of if (t==reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[scala.Int]). How to solve this?

Comment: You need a stable identifier for pattern matching if not using `if`, and you want to use `=:=` rather than `==`. Try `case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => ...`

Comment: Pattern matching is not a good idea: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/P2_okWT4muw/88KPDtoXOz8J. So, do as @lmm recommends you, use `if` statements and `=:=`.

Answer (score 6):

The `TypeTag` API has a comparison operator `=:=` and a method for obtaining the `Type` instance for a given class, you can combine these with guards to obtain the desired result:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def test(t: Type) {
  t match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => println("int")
    case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => println("string")
    case _ =>  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As lmm and n1r3 pointed out, you might be better off to use an if here. However, you could do something like the following:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
case class TypeComparer[A](typeToCompare: TypeTag[A]){
  def unapply(universeType: Type) = universeType =:= typeToCompare.tpe
}

object TypeComparer{
  val IntComparer = new TypeComparer(typeTag[Int])
}

object TestObject{
  def tester(t: Type) {
    t match {
      case TypeComparer.IntComparer() => println("pass")
      case _ =>  println("fail")
    }
  }   

  def test[A](implicit ev: TypeTag[A]) = tester(typeOf[A])
}
```

which you can run like:

```
TestObject.test[Int] //pass
TestObject.test[Boolean] //fail
```

The downside is that you need to create a concrete object for every comparer as I do not know of a way to have companion object with a type used in the `apply`

So, it is a bit verbose....and the if is probably better here.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a workaround:

```
def test(t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type) {
  t.toString match {
    case "Int" => \\ ...
    case "scala.Int" => \\ ...
    case "Double" => \\ ...
    case "scala.Double" => \\ ...
    case "String" => \\ ... 
    case _ =>  \\ ...
  }
}
```

However, is there a better solution that avoids going via strings?